# Why file cannot be found to copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am writing a batch script which will copy a file from a folder into the C:\ drive:

```
@ECHO ON
COPY C:\RANDOMFILES\Weekly Reprort_Hew*.xls C:\Weekly Reprort_Hew???????????.xls
```

The filename in the RANDOMFILES folder is: `Weekly Reprort_Hew, 6-29-2014 10-30-00 PM-642.xls` (The date and time and the number at the end will always change so I used the `*` in the filename being copied in the script)

When I run the batch script, I get the following message:

```
c:\RANDOMFILES>COPY C:\RANDOMFILES\Weekly Reprort_Hewlett*.xls C:\Weekly Reprort
_Hewlett???????????.xls
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: What's with the `?`?  Or is that why you are asking?

Comment: Based on some search I found the `?` will be what is kept from the original filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes to handle spaces etc.  Double check the spelling too.

```
@ECHO ON
COPY "C:\RANDOMFILES\Weekly Reprort_Hew*.xls" "C:\Weekly Reprort_Hew???????????.xls"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using single quote and didn't work. Can I also do the same thing if the it was in a different server rather than local? Or would CMD need different permission?

Comment: If you use the `"\\server\share\file two.xls"` format, and you have permission to write to the folder, then you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it is not working - is it hidden?  Maybe the spaces in the name?

The following will work though:

```
FOR %%I in (C:\RANDOMFILES\Weekly Reprort_Hew*.xls) DO COPY "%%I" C:\
```

The destination file name isn't necessary; if not otherwise specified, it will remain unchanged provided the destination is different.  That may be why the plain `COPY` command isn't working.

Also:

> "It is an not-so-well-known fact that the question mark wildcard will match exactly one character only when the wildcard does not appear at the end of a file name. " from http://www.thefriendlycoder.com/2011/11/24/batch-file-gotcha-question-mark-wildcard/

Comment: I just had to put double quotes as the other user stated. I tried single quote and it wasn't working :/. Thanks for the response. Up Voted.

Comment: Why I didn't include that in my answer is because I was able to copy the file with spaces without quotes in my test.  Go figure.